# when types selected from dropdown his category and subcategory should be shown in dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

```
  1) when types selected from dropdown his category and subcategory should be shown 
   in dropdown,problem : when we select types in category it is showing all the category
   and all the subcategory of other types also
   please solve this problem as soon as possible.

   inventory_list.php
    <select name="typ_id" id="typ_id">
     <option>Select a Type</option>
      <?php
       $get_types = "select * from types";
      $run_types = mysql_query($get_types);
     while ($row_types=mysql_fetch_array($run_types)){
          $typ_id= $row_types['typ_id'];
         $typ_name = $row_types['typ_name'];
       echo "<option value='$typ_id'>$typ_name</option>";     
      }
    ?>

    <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
    <option>Select a Category</option>
   <?php
     $get_category = "SELECT * FROM category ";
     $run_category = mysql_query($get_category);
     while ($row_category=mysql_fetch_array($run_category)){
         $cat_id= $row_category['cat_id'];
         $cat_name = $row_category['cat_name'];
      echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_name</option>";      
      }
    ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: Please check tutorial for MySQL query with WHERE conditions.
https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AzaBVNihLtLAuASLo4GgDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=mysql+select+with+condition

Comment: You can also refer this ans link for the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795351/dynamic-dropdownlist-value-from-database/20795573#20795573

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
<script>
 function get_category(type_id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_category.php",
            data: { type_id : type_id } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#category").html(data);
        });
  }
</script>

<select name="typ_id" id="typ_id" onchange="get_category(this)">
     <option>Select a Type</option>
      <?php
       $get_types = "select * from types";
      $run_types = mysql_query($get_types);
     while ($row_types=mysql_fetch_array($run_types)){
          $typ_id= $row_types['typ_id'];
         $typ_name = $row_types['typ_name'];
       echo "<option value='$typ_id'>$typ_name</option>";     
      }
    ?>

<div id='category'></div>
```

get_category.php

```
    <?php
         $get_category = "SELECT * FROM category where type_id = $_POST['type_id']";
         $run_category = mysql_query($get_category);
         echo '<select name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
        <option>Select a Category</option>';

         while ($row_category=mysql_fetch_array($run_category)){
             $cat_id= $row_category['cat_id'];
             $cat_name = $row_category['cat_name'];
          echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_name</option>";      
          }
    echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: after selecting types from dropdown category dropdown is not coming and what will be html of category.

Comment: use onchange="get_category(this.value)" instead of onchange="get_category(this)"
and don't forget to include jquery file

Comment: inventory_list.php    <tr>
        <td align="right"><strong>Types</strong></td>
        <td><label>
  <script>
              function get_category(type_id){
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "get_category.php",
                   data: { type_id : type_id } 
                   }).done(function(data){
                   $("#category").html(data);
                   });
                   }
        </script>

Comment: inventory_list.php     <select name="typ_id" id="typ_id" onchange="get_category(this.value)">
     <option>Select a Type</option>
          <?php
  
   $get_types = "select * from types";
   
   $run_types = mysql_query($get_types);
   
   while ($row_types=mysql_fetch_array($run_types)){
   
       $typ_id= $row_types['typ_id'];
    $typ_name = $row_types['typ_name'];
   
    echo "<option value='$typ_id'>$typ_name</option>";
          
    }
      ?>
  </select>
      </label></td>
      </tr>

Comment: <tr>
        <td align="right"><strong>Category</strong></td>
        <td><label>
        <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
  <option>Select a Subategory</option>
  
       </select>
        </label></td>
      </tr>

Comment: dropdown category is not coming

Comment: <tr> <td align="right" id="category"><strong>Category</strong></td> <td>

assign id=category to td

Comment: replace <td align="right" id="category"><strong>Category</strong></td>
see id="category" this is what you are missing

Comment: where we will write  id="category" we are not understanding please help with full code

Comment: on your category td Ok replace your code with this <tr> <td align="right" id='category'><strong>Category</strong></td> <td><label> <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id"> <option>Select a Subategory</option> </select> </label></td> </tr>